# How to get a hex file for Samd21 from .ino file

Tags: arduino-zero

Can you generate a .hex file from an .ino file for the Atsamd21-zero?
I can generate a .bin file but not a .hex file.

Comment: what do you want to do with a hex file?

Comment: I want to combine the bootloader which is in .hex with the Samd21 file which is in .elf or .bin format.

Comment: and then what? bin is uploaded

Comment: in platform.txt `build.preferred_out_format=bin`

Comment: You can also manually do it with a `arm-none-eabi-objcopy` call (this tool is somewhere in your arduino IDE tool folder for the SAMD21 platform) if you do `arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex input.bin output.hex`